# angular 4 pass data between components without input\output

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm trying to pass data between components in angular 4.
I don't want to use input\output.
in Homecomponent I want to push data into service and in page2 component I want to get data from service.
I just looked on way with observable and subject and I tried to implement it without success.

HomeComponent

```
    import { ClientService } from './../clinet-service.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: 'pages/home/home.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  clients = ['john', 'jane']
  clientFound = false

  // constructor(private navController: NavController) { }
  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {

  }

  openClient(client) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.subject.next([
      { name: 'Harold', age: 35 }
    ]
    );

}

}
```

page2component

```
import { ClientService } from './../clinet-service.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-2',
  template: '{{clients}}'
})
export class Page2Component {
  client:any;

  constructor(  private clientService: ClientService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    debugger
    let clients = this.clientService.observable.subscribe(clients => console.log(clients));
  }
}
```

clientService

```
import { Injectable, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()

export class ClientService {
  subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  observable: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable();


}
```

actually I didn't like the way of implementation because i try to make simple thing such push data to service and get it in other components but I can't do that.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: I don't see nothing in page2

Comment: You are not getting anything in console?

Comment: yes i don't get anything

Comment: What happens when you remove the debugger line from Page2Component in ngOnInit method?

Comment: Works just fine in plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/1M3bJyTH5g4pVq2UYZ6F?p=preview

Comment: I tried this way without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because you make it unnecessary complicated. Here is how you should do :

**HomeComponent**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.subject.next([{
      {name: 'Harold', age: 35 },
      {name: 'Kumar', age: 40 },
    }]);
}
```

**page2Component**

```
ngOnInit(){
  let clients = this.clientService.observable.subscribe(clients => console.log(clients));
}
```

**service**

```
export class ClientService {

  subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  observable: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that in parent and child project and the child load before the parent and it not works so I decided to do that with observable

Comment: Well if you use an API after that (I guess that your service is mocked), you won't have this problem, since you won't set your clients, but just get them. To check that, you can set the clients in the service directly where you declare the clients variable.

Comment: it works but it's not what I want to do. I want from parent component to get data and then to save in service and share with all childs.. all childs use get function to get data in their components

Comment: Well for that, unmock your service and edit your post. Then, we'll work on that. Because if you don't, we'll use concepts that aren't related to a real API service.

Comment: what do you mean @trichetriche?

Comment: I mean that when you use an API call to a back-end, you will deal with observables, and implicitly with subjects. But if you mock the calls, you will deal explicitly with both. I can make you an example of that, but you will delete it when you unmock your service

Comment: did u check it before? because it's not working. not show any data in page2

Comment: I literally copied it from a working project I'm working on. Do you have any errors ?

Comment: no but I did debugger and it looks in the observable it throws any error but not show in console. not sure

Comment: I expressly used a console log to show you the data. Get rid of the debugger and try to see the log.

Comment: yes, it not show me any error. can you please show me in plunker?

Comment: I edited my post, maybe you see anything missing there?

Comment: [Here is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IGLzbcHTqTyiQ7PXl9FO?p=preview), I forgot a timeout, sorry

Comment: this way works but when I navigate first to home page and then to page2 it not works, maybe because the page refresh?

Comment: Because you destroy the timeout. Simply remove the '2000' into the settimeout function.

Comment: it like it was before without timeout. it's not works.

Comment: It does on my side. You did something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your HomeComponent decorator is broken. You need to use `templateUrl` instead of `template` when you are using external template file.

Wrong

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: 'pages/home/home.html',
})
```

Correct

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'pages/home/home.html',
})
```

https://angular.io/api/core/Component

Comment: i did it in purpose just write a text with the url

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data between any of the componenrs using rxjs subject. Create new rxjs subject in your service like this

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    myNewSubject = new Subject<any>();

    informDataChanges(passyourobject){
      this.myNewSubject.next(passyourobject);
  }
```

}

When change happens in your component or you want to pass data to another component simply call this service function from your component and pass data as parameter to this function. You can do that with something like this

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-some',
      templateUrl: './some.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
    })
    export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor( private myService: MyService) { }

      someFunction(){
        this.myService.informLogout('somedata');//Passing data to service here
      }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Now all you need to do is subscribe to that data in another component. IMPORTANT subject keeps on watches any changes to it, and data will be continuous stream and it will be automatically subscribed. So it is best to subscribe to the subject in the constructor, and changes will be immediately reflected in that component.

You do it with some thing like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-another',
          templateUrl: './another.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./another.component.css']
        })
        export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor( private myService: MyService) {
            this.myService.myNewSubject.subscribe(data=>{
             console.log(data);
       }) 
}
```

This way you can pass data between any number of components and any number of components can use the same subject.