# How can we communicate between two component without using @input and @output decorator?

Tags: angular, components

How can we communicate between two component without using @input and @output decorator??

I was going through one interview and they asked me about component interaction on keypress. When we type any key in component1 then it will print on component2.

can any one help me how to do so?

Comment: I think you could use the service. In one component, you pass arguments to the observable in the service. In the other component, you subscribe to the observable.

Comment: Using Subjects both with services. This is especially good approach when you need cross-component communication (nested child components).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 4 pass data between components without input\output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092040/angular-4-pass-data-between-components-without-input-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **services** for this issue.

By creating a service, you can declare **Subjects** that can be subscribed to by any component using the service.

If you create a service

```
export class MyService {
  message = new Subject<string>();

  public setMessage(message: string) {
    this.message.next(message);
  }
}
```

Than you can use this service in any component using dependency injection:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
}
```

Subject type beeing an Observable, you can subscribe to it (usually in the **ngOnInit()** lifecycle hook)

```
liveMessage = 'This is Component1!';

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myserviceService.liveMessage.subscribe(msg => {
      this.liveMessage = msg;
  });
}
```

Now your component will react to the changes that are made to **message** and since in your subscription you always set your components property (*liveMessage*) equal to the message in the service, it can be used to communicate between multiple components.

If you inject this service to another component as above, you could call **setMessage()**, triggered by every character change in your case:

```
onSetValue() {
    this.myService.setMessage('This is a message from Component2!');
}
```

So technically you've established communication from Component2 towards Component1.